# virt-manager vm console requires password

Tags: password, console, foreman, virt-manager

I have just started learning foreman. I added a KVM host to the foreman as a compute resource.

I can now provision VMs from foreman now but I cannot view the console of the VMs that are provisioned from foreman as I am prompted for a password.

[image: Console requesting password]

I am now sure what is requesting this password? I search for a couple of days but did not find any related posts.

Following is the XML dump:

```
[root@kvmhost ~]# virsh dumpxml test3.redhat.local
<domain type='kvm' id='2'>
  <name>test3.redhat.local</name>
  <uuid>3e9c8745-8071-4f8a-be2e-1288a739202a</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>1048576</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>1048576</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-rhel7.0.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='network'/>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/test3.redhat.local-disk1'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='piix3-uhci'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'>
      <alias name='pci.0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:77:2c:7b'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <target dev='vnet1'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/1'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input2'/>
    </input>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5904' autoport='yes' listen='0.0.0.0'>
      <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='selinux' relabel='yes'>
    <label>system_u:system_r:svirt_t:s0:c81,c368</label>
    <imagelabel>system_u:object_r:svirt_image_t:s0:c81,c368</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='dac' relabel='yes'>
    <label>+107:+107</label>
    <imagelabel>+107:+107</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>
```

Cheers,
J

Comment: Please show the virtual machine XML definition. You can get it with `sudo virsh dumpxml test3.redhat.local`.

Comment: The graphics should be set to SPICE and video QXL, not VNC and Cirrus. Shutdown the VM, change the video settings and try again.

Comment: I was looking at the "Display VNC" in the VM properties and saw a "password" checkbox. I unticked the box and now can view the console.Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Michael Hampton for pointing in the right direction.

I unchecked the following box to view the console.

[Remove Console password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE9fB.png)

Comment: That gets rid of the password, but you still should use SPICE/QXL.

Comment: Just curious, what is the advantage of using SPICE over VNC? I had never heard of SPICE before starting to learn libvirt. Cheers.

Comment: Performance, better video support on modern operating systems, better integration with the VM viewer...